# Is there a way to be notified of new data becoming available in an SSLSocket (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, sockets, asynchronous, tcpsocket

I'm working on building a custom client on top of Ruby's [`SSLSocket`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLSocket.html).  In order to receive data, I've been using the `read` and `read_nonblock` methods provided by the [`OpenSSL::Buffering`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Buffering.html) module.

I'm now trying to take what I have so far, and make it so that I can define a callback (via a user-defined block) that will be run when messages are received.  It looks like I basically need to implement something alone these lines:

```
thread = Thread.new do
  while !socket.closed?
    while (data = socket.read_nonblock(1024) rescue nil)
      @buffer << data
    end

    sleep 0.1

    # ... parse full messages from @buffer & deliver to callbacks ...
  end
end

thread.run
```

The problem I have with this approach is that it's not truly event-driven, and there can be up to a 100ms delay since the data was actually available.  Sure, I could change the sleep time, but it just feels a bit hack-ish.

Is there a better approach I could be using for this?  If not, what concerns should I have should I decide to implement a shorter/faster loop (e.g.: `sleep 0.01`)?

Comment: OK, first, if you've threaded it off, why are you fixated on non-blocking?

Comment: @MartinJames - My assumption was that if I take out the sleep call, it'll end up just eating memory in that loop.  Perhaps I'm under the wrong impression though.

Comment: Did you look at `Kernel.select` method? The [https://github.com/celluloid/nio4r] uses this approach for pure Ruby implementation.

Comment: I wasn't previously familiar with that method, I'll check it out!  Thanks, @tlewin :)

Comment: It should work. The `EventMachine` gem do it out of the box. It is a really good piece of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two way to achieve it.

**1)** Using `Kernel.select` or `IO.select` method (both are the same):

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

s     = TCPSocket.new(host, prot) 
ssl   = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(s)
ssl.connect

t = Thread.new do
  loop do
    sr, sw = IO.select [ssl]
    puts sr.first.readline
    puts '...'
  end
end

puts 'start reading'
t.join # join the main thread
```

The `IO.select` waits until some data arrived, without the busy loop. The benefit of this solution, it's only uses the standard Ruby library.

**2)** Using `EventMachine` library:

```
require 'eventmachine'

module Client

  def post_init
    start_tls
  end

  def receive_data data
    # include callback code
    puts data
    puts '...'
  end

end

EM.run do 
  # start event loop
  EM.connect 'localhost', 9000, Client
end
```

`EventMachine`, according to the documentation, is an event-driven I/O using the Reactor pattern.

The `EventMachine` has all you need *out of the box*. The reactor is implemented in C++ and the thread model is outside the Ruby GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which makes the library extremely fast.

I have been using it on production for a while and works great!

The both approach will work as you asking for, so I would recommend to benchmark them and see which one fits best to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response and exposing me to a couple methods I've never seen/used!  I'm familiar with EventMachine, but wasn't aware that I could use it for SSL sockets.  I'll definitely check it out!